# How to use Tensorflow to train Poisson regression?

Tags: tensorflow, regression

I want to train a Poisson regression to compare with the log(Y) linear regression in Tensorflow. However, I've only found [tf.contrib.distributions.Poisson](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/Poisson). 
Can anyone offer some insight to help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

those days I find one function maybe help:

```
loss = tf.nn.log_poisson_loss(targets=batch_labels, log_input=logits)
```